# Scala - Create Multiple List from a list

Tags: list, scala, flatmap

flatMap takes integer input from command line. 
A list must be generated with the input number of elements in the list starting from one. 
Therefore, when input is 3, `List(1,2,3)` must be generated. 
Each number in the List generated `numberList = List(1,2,3)` 
must be used to create separate lists with elements equal to the number starting from 1. 
Therefore, when input is 3; List(1), List(1, 2), List(1,2,3) 
must be created and joined together to give output resultList as `List(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)`

Comment: What is the logic behind the input and output? What have you tried? which restrictions do you have?

Comment: Take integer from command line.. say 3. it should create output as List(1,2,3).. Then this as a Input will create O/P as  List(1), List(1, 2), List(1,2,3).. then final output will be List(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3).

Comment: object flatMapUsage{
 def main(args :Array[String]){
  val input :Int = args(0).toInt
  val numberList = List.tabulate(input)(input=>input+1)
  def listGenerator = ((1 to Input.size).map(x => Input.take(x)).mkString(", "))
  val resultList = numberList.flatMap(listGenerator)
  println(resultList)
  println(resultList.length)


 } 
}

Comment: Please edit the question and format correctly your code instead of adding comments. -BTW, just to make sure I understand, the idea is to create a final list which contains all the elements from `1` to `n`, where after reaching each new element, it starts over and over again.

Comment: what happens when n = 4 ? Does it loop through the intermediate loop again : List(1), List(1,2) , List(1,2,3), List(1,2,3,4) ?  What is the output you are expecting. Is it List(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4)

Comment: Yes...it should create 4 list then those 4 list willl be input and create List(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 2):

A 1-liner (just for fun).

```
def f(n :Int) = (n to 1 by -1).tails.flatten.toList.reverse
```

or

```
def f(n :Int) = List.tabulate(n)(x => 1 to (x+1)).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic you need, you can adapt it to your precise use case.
Also, you would need to add all the other details like input and output.

```
def foo(n: Int): List[Int] = {
  def listUntil(x: Int): List[Int] =
    List.range(start = 1, end = (x  + 1))

  listUntil(n).flatMap(listUntil)
}
```

Comment: Actually, we had the same answer. Hence deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly for input n=3 you expect the output (1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3), and for input n=4, you expect the output (1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4).

If that's the case, it is as simple as

```
def f(n: Int) = for {
  i <- (1 to n)
  j <- (1 to i)
} yield j
```

I tried this on ammonite and get

```
@ def f(n: Int) = for {
    i <- (1 to n)
    j <- (1 to i)
  } yield j
defined function f

@ f(3)
res2: collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)

@ f(4)
res3: collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: @Raj For comprehension is also a nice way of handling this kind of problems in scala. It is clearer to read when you have many nested map and flatMap logic